# SQL Subquery doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a subquery like this

```
SELECT GenreNaam, 
GenreCount = (SELECT COUNT(GK.GenreID) 
              FROM GenreKoppel GK 
              WHERE GK.GenreID = G.GenreID) 
FROM Genre G
```

But I get error

> 1054 - Unknown column 'GenreCount' in 'field list'

I am new to subquery's what am I doing wrong.

Comment: I don't think mysql supports giving column aliases using: `Alias = something`, you should try `something as GenreCount`

Comment: `GenreCount =` ? is that valid?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is in SQL Server, but I think it's not supported in mysql

Comment: @Lamak Ah. Yeah I guess I should have phrased that as *"is that valid in MySQL?"* had I known that ;-) and now I do. I thought that looked rather strange.

Comment: @Fred-ii- However, it IS valid MySQL; it just means something different! (and so won't work if there's no genrecount column in genre)

Comment: @Strawberry I'd say something to the effect of "Select 2 columns equals X" and MySQL is probably interpreting that as them wanting to do math, or an "assignment" of sorts.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OK. But, as indicated by the error message, an alternative interpretation is equally valid (if a little clumsy): http://rextester.com/NKO61852

Comment: @Strawberry *Interesting*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using SQL Server style alias definitions, which don't work in MySQL.  Instead, use `AS` to indicate an alias (or simply just state the name of the alias after the subquery).

```
SELECT GenreNaam,
       (SELECT COUNT(GK.GenreID) FROM GenreKoppel GK
        WHERE GK.GenreID = G.GenreID) AS GenreCount   -- or just GenreCount
FROM Genre G
```

This query could also be written using a join:

```
SELECT G.GenreNaam,
       COALESCE(GK.GenreCount, 0) AS GenreCount
FROM Genre G
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT GenreID, COUNT(*) AS GenreCount
    FROM GenreKoppel
    GROUP BY GenreID
) GK
    ON G.GenreID = GK.GenreID
```

This alternative approach also uses a subquery, but it is not correlated unlike the one in your original query.  I would expect the join approach to run faster in general.

Comment: Thanks, I looked up some examples on the internet and didn't realise it would not work in mysql

Comment: Why did this get a downvote? or have I missed something?

Comment: Tim, are you smoking something?

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is a rogue bandit who keeps downvoting me.  Bar fight or something...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know the feeling, believe me. Edit: Seems like it wasn't the bar after all ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's my downvote. AS is an optional keyword. It's omission or otherwise has no bearing on the matter.

Comment: @Strawberry well, least you were honest/open about it (I admire that). However, Tim did outline the initial error of `=` not being a valid aliasing in MySQL. I think you were a bit too hard on him ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm actually still unclear on that point. Which aspect of that is valid in SQL Server?

Comment: @Strawberry Lamak pointed [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507312/sql-subquery-doesnt-work#comment70220207_41507312) in comments.

Comment: Oh, I see now - yes, that means something entirely different in MySQL.